# MYSQL: How to convert VARCHAR column containing dates to a DATE column?

Tags: mysql, date, varchar

I have a large table of birthdays that I want to convert from a varchar column to a date column.

The table SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE `birthdays` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthday_date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

The birthday date is stored in one of two ways: strings like "05/26/1994" or sometimes "03/14" (for people who don't want to reveal their birth year).

**What is the best way to create another table and store the birthdays in a date column?**  Is it possible to do this just using MySQL (and avoid using PHP or some other intermediary)?

I have found a STR_TO_DATE function in MySQL. Should I use this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't - date is consist of YYY-MM-DD, missing information on Year will be a problem for STR_TO_DATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(birthday_date RLIKE '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}',STR_TO_DATE(birthday_date,'%m/%d/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(birthday_date,'%m/%d'));
```

This will result in dates like 0000-03-14 for rows that have no year entered. Your server needs to be configured to allow invalid dates though (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html )

Comment: Thanks! That's very useful. In general, do dates stored with year 0000 ever cause problems? I've never stored a date or a datetime without a specific year before.

Comment: There are several issues. Most obvious will be with sorting these dates (they will group at the beginning). There are also portability issues - if you ever need to migrate this data to other server, you need to make sure it allows invalid dates. Migrating to other RDBMS can also be tricky.

Comment: The minimum supported date for DATETIME is 1000-01-01, so you might want to use year 1000 instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your column to DateTime then you will **not be able** to store dates like "03/14" in which year is missing. So instead I suggest to keep this as it is and probably have another column for storing the dateTime if you really need that. 
Also have internal trigger to convert the datestrings from varchar column to dateTime column.

yes, you have to use the method [STR_TO_DATE](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/STRTODATEstrformat.htm) for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. General question: If the table is millions of rows, would it better to store birthdays as a varchar or try to store them as dates (and possibly store the birthdays without years as something like 03/14/0000)?

Comment: @Eric - generally its always better to store dates as dateTime field itself probably because you will have a standard format for saving and should be easy to compare with other dates as well. For eg:- all users who are born in this year. etc. The year '0000', I dont know if it is valid, but yes you can give some vague value like 1500 or something.