# Changing the column Type in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey I have an SQL Table which has a column for storing date but the date column has a type varchar. I want to change the type to date but I don't want the actual data to be lost in that column. How can I achieve that.

Manually taking a backup of the table and then entering each entry? or there is some other cool way to do it ? Actually the data is huge

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL: How to convert VARCHAR column containing dates to a DATE column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223971/mysql-how-to-convert-varchar-column-containing-dates-to-a-date-column)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My way of doing this:

(1) Add a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable 
ADD COLUMN `new_date` DATE NULL AFTER `views`;
```

(2) Update the new column

```
UPDATE yourtable SET new_date = old_date;
```

Take care of the datas formatting in `old_date`. If it isn't formatted `yyyy-mm-dd`, you might have to [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) or some string-replacements in this `UPDATE`-statement here to fit your purposes.

*Example:*

If your data looks like this: `mmmm dd, yyyy, hh:mm` (p.e. `May 17, 2012, 8:36 pm`) , you can update like this:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(old_date, "%M %e, %Y");
```

[`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) basically reverse engineers string data to a date value.

(3) Delete the old column

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable 
DROP COLUMN `old_date`;
```

(4) Rename the new column

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable 
CHANGE `new_date` `old_date` DATE NULL;
```

Done!

Comment: Can you provide some sample code for the step 2. the date column contains something like this currently May 17, 2012, 8:36 pm and I want like 2012-05-17

Comment: I run this query it said no rows effected... UPDATE mc_boxes_has_downloads SET new_date = DATE_FORMAT(old_date , ' %Y-%m-%d ');

Comment: The current column has varchar type

Comment: I mean, what is the formatting of the current data in this varchar field?

Comment: it displays date like this May 17, 2012, 8:36 pm

Comment: I have one other problem if you can have a look at it. I will be thankful to you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980168/get-the-empty-records-using-sql

Answer (score 1):

What about:

1) Adding a new column with the right type

2) Updating your new column with the parsed dates

3) Removing the old column

Update to fill the date pattern parsing requirement:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 17, 2012, 8:36 pm','%M %d, %Y');
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code for the step 2. the date column contains something like this currently May 17, 2012, 8:36 pm and I want like 2012-05-17

Comment: It's as simple as SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 17, 2012, 8:36 pm','%M %d, %Y');

Comment: I am trying this UPDATE mc_boxes_has_downloads SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(date , ' %Y-%m-%d '); but it is not affecting any row

Comment: Why did you change the pattern from my '%M %d, %Y' to '%Y-%m-%d' ?

Comment: Ok I understand :) The pattern is necessary to tell the str_to_date function how is written the date as a string. You must not change this if the old date is as you say 'May 17, 2012, 8:36 pm'. Don't worry for the formatting in the new column, it will be stored as a Date and the format is not a concern :)

Comment: Refer to Bjoern's answer, I'm giving up :D

Comment: No thanks to you as well for giving your precious time to me. Thanks guys. U all rock

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMNNAME Datatype
```

e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE Users MODIFY RegisterDate DateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column with data type you want, then run an UPDATE query to copy the data from the old column to the new column. and then delete the the old column.

Note that perhaps you will have to use the CONVERT function to convert the date string into a datetime.